# TFS express error: The working folder C:\LocalFolder is already in use

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I am using VS 2015 and I am working on a project that has a local workspace on *C:\LocalFolder* mapped to *$/ServerFolder*

At some point VS 2015 crashed  while I was trying to explore the Source Control, so I had to kill the devenv.exe process...

Next, when I reopened the solution, the workspace is not mapped!
*Local Path: not Mapped*

So, I have tried to re-map the folder, but I get this error:

> The working folder *C:\LocalFolder* is already in use by the workspace
> ***COMPUTER_NAME**;User* on computer **COMPUTER_NAME**

**EDIT**

Following someone's advice I have tried to clear the cache on:

C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache\

Deleted all the folder content, but got the same error.

Comment: is your C:\LocalFolder empty?

Comment: no, the c:\LocalFolder is where I have all my code with the latest local changes

Answer (score 2):

In TFS, one local folder can only map one workspace. You may not select the correct WORKSPACE which you are working on.

Open Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio , click drop down button. Select the workspace which you are working on before.(For you ,COMPUTER_NAME  ) 
[image]

Comment: This is exactly what happened to my colleague, thanks for the screenshot and pointing out the Workspace dropdown in the Source Control Explorer window! +1

Answer (score 1):

Experienced similar issue "The working folder is already in use by the workspace". Spent ages trying various suggested solutions found here and on other forums, but none of them seemed to work.

Using Window 10 (1709), VS Pro 2017 - connecting to TFS 2017 on remote server.

The fix that finally worked for me was to rename my Windows 10 computer (Windows, Setting, System, About, 'Rename this PC'). Restarted the PC - created new Workspace and mapped to local drive. All worked well after that.

Not ideal for everyone, but a good potential solution if all else fails.

Comment: I spent quite a bit of time trying various TF commands, clearing cache, and other suggestions to no avail. Your solution got me passed the issue, like cutting melted butter. My problem is that this method glosses over the real underlying issue. One issue that I had was deleting the workspace on the server. Oh well, I am passed the problem  now. Thanks.

Comment: @SarahWeinberger - I've been sleeping peacefully and been very happy since I started using GitLab. It integrates very nicely with VS and my only regret is that I didn't make this switch 5 years earlier. imo, TFS is an absolute nightmare!