# TFS express error opening Visual Studio 2015 solution

Tags: tfs

I have a solution in VS2015 bound to a TFS Express Server for source control.

All worked well till yesterday, but this morning, when I open the solution I get this Message:

**The Solution is bound to Source Control on the following Source Control Server:
http://tfsexpress:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
Would you like to contact the server to try to enable source control integration?**

I haven't done any changes on the server but maybe there are some problems there... I have checked the Event Viewer on the server but I didn't see any errror?
What does I have to check on the server?
Could you give me some advice?

**NOTE**

The VS Team Foundation output says:

The solution you have loaded is bound to the source control server at http://tfsexpress:8080/tfs/defaultcollection, but no workspace on that
server could be located. If you do have a workspace on this server, and you want this solution to be opened under source control,
connect to that server using Team Explorer and then re-open the solution.

**UPDATE 2**

*I have made [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33499686/tfs-express-error-the-working-folder-c-localfolder-is-already-in-use/33516525#33516525) on the same topic, but since that post is the following of the story, I will join it here:*

After I have opened the solution, click "Ok" to the Error Message to continue.

Now the workspace appears as not mapped:
*Local Path: not Mapped*

If I try to re-map the workspace I get this error:
(I re-map using 
- Source Control->Advanced->Workspaces...
- Manage Workspaces->Edit...
- Source Control Folder 
  $/ServerFolder
  Local Folder
  ... -> I choose the C:\LocalFolder)

The working folder *C:\LocalFolder* is already in use by the workspace ***COMPUTER_NAME***;User on computer **COMPUTER_NAME**

**NOTE 2**

Following someone's other advice I have tried to clear the cache on:

c:\Users\*username*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache\

Deleted all the folder content, but got the same error.

**UPDATE 3**

To be able to continue my work I have created a new folder in C:\SourceCode

Have re-done the mapping onto this folder, TFS has checked out all the server code, I have manually rebuilt all projects, Nugets folders, ecc... (a mess) but at this point I'm not so sure that everything will compile (and run!) smoothly...
So I really like to understand what problem has occurred and how I can re-map my originally *C:\LocalFolder*

**UPDATE 4**

> tf workspaces /format:detailed

================================================================================

```
Area di lavoro: MY-XXX 
Proprietario  : *ME* Admin.
Computer      : MY-XXX 
Commento      :  
Raccolta      : tfsexpress\DefaultCollection 
Autorizzazioni: Private 
Percorso      : Locale 
Ora file      : Corrente

Cartelle di lavoro:  $/KKK: C:\SourceCode\KKK
```

> tf workspaces /owner:*

```
================================================================================
Area di lavoro: MY-XXX
Proprietario  : *ME*
Computer      : MY-XXX
Commento      : 
Raccolta      : tfsexpress\DefaultCollection
Autorizzazioni: Private
Percorso      : Locale
Ora file      : Corrente

Cartelle di lavoro:
 $/XXX: C:\XXX
 $/YYY: C:\YYY
 $/ZZZ: C:\ZZZ


================================================================================
Area di lavoro: MY-XXX
Proprietario  : *ME* Admin.
Computer      : MY-XXX
Commento      : 
Raccolta      : tfsexpress\DefaultCollection
Autorizzazioni: Private
Percorso      : Locale
Ora file      : Corrente

Cartelle di lavoro:
 **$/KKK: C:\SourceCode\KKK**
```

So, the problem seems to be: I have the mapped workspace with the **ME admin** account, but I want it mapped to the *ME* account.

Incidentally, as I am logged to Windows with the *ME* windows account, how is that TFS has used the *ME admin* when I have done the mapping in UPDATE 3???

**UPDATE 5**

I deleted the *ME admin* associated workspace.

Then I removed the windows credential for the TFS server (that was the culprit for VS2015 to automatically create a workspace for my *ME admin* account)

Now all is working again!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my environment, I reproduce your problem following below steps:
1.Delete a workspace which have local mapped folders such as E:\TFS
2.Open a solution  through VS in E:\TFS
3.Get the same error message as you

So you  can use the `tf workspaces` command to check whether you have workspace on the current computer. If not, then create one. If you already have, right click on your solution or project and map it to your local disk. Then re-open the solution.

Due to your question asked before: [TFS express error: The working folder C:\LocalFolder is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33499686/tfs-express-error-the-working-folder-c-localfolder-is-already-in-use)  You just need to make sure you are working on the right workspace and  your C:\LocalFolder is mapped with the workspace.

**Update**

You can check your account info which is connected to TFS by move the mouse to **Connect** bar in Team Exploer. It will show as below picture
[image]

To change your user account,you need to delete your account information which stored in Windows Credentials(Control Panel-Credential Manager). When you reopen TeamExploer(VS), you will need to enter your account.

Comment: I thought to have only one active workspace, that is from within VS2015 I see only one workspace... but if I use the command line something strange appears... See my UPDATE 4

Comment: Accrodding to you last post , it seems the different user your are using when created the workspace mapping.

Comment: I am sure that when I was using VS the first time, and also after when a created a new workspace mapping to a different folder, I was logged with the normal account... Something happed that "fooled" TFS or VS? Now how can I restore the correct owner?